# How to use AWS Amplify Auth Without AWS Cognito or AWS User Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

How can we use `AWS Amplify Auth` Without `AWS Cognito` or `AWS Userpool`?

We want to store user data in the database(for example `Dynamo DB`) and get user authenticated from that.

We are using `NextJS` and want to use React `Context` to manage user sessions with SSR.

Is this possible?